# Ставится ли запятая? Управление образования на основании письма во исполнение приказа в рамках проекта

Tags: запятые

*Управление образования на основании письма ГБУ ДПО Республики Марий Эл «Марийский институт образования» во исполнение приказа Министерства образования 17.12.2021 №1152 «О внесении изменений в приказ Министерства образования и науки Республики Марий Эл от 17 декабря 2021 года №1152» в рамках реализации региональной Дорожной карты проекта адресной методической помощи «500+» информирует о проведении мониторинга готовности концептуальных документов школ-участниц данного проекта.*

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу причин для хоть одной запятой.

Answer (score 0):

**В таком виде запятые не нужны.** Но эта фраза трудна для восприятия. Можно разделить на две, как бы "основную" и "пояснение".

Будет так.

Управление образования информирует о проведении мониторинга готовности концептуальных документов школ-участниц проекта адресной методической помощи «500+».
Основания:
письмо ГБУ ДПО Республики Марий Эл «Марийский институт образования»;
приказ Министерства образования 17.12.2021 №1152 «О внесении изменений в приказ Министерства образования и науки Республики Марий Эл от 17 декабря 2021 года №1152»;
реализация региональной Дорожной карты проекта.

Первое предложение тоже можно упростить: "Управление образования проверит готовность..." Тем самым вы как раз информируете.

Comment: Эта фраза такой шедевр канцелярита, что лучше оставить нетронутой, как музейный экспонат)